# Select item1 from tuple list where item2 is specified

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of tuples like:

```
List<Tuple<XElement, int>> allNodes = new List<Tuple<XElement, int>>();
```

I need to get specific XElement where item2 (index) is specific.
Tried something like this, but got an error:

```
XElement parent = allNodes.Where(x => x.Item2 == 5).Select(x => x.Item1);
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'

Comment: You are missing `FisrtOrDefault()`. `Where` returns an enumerable because there are potentially more than one element that will meet the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your code returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which is not what you want as a result, instead you can utilise the `FirstOrDefault` eager operation to retrieve only a single object:

```
XElement parent = allNodes.Where(x => x.Item2 == 5)
                          .Select(x => x.Item1)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

or if each tuple index is supposed to be unique then it's probably better to use `SingleOrDefault()`.

```
XElement parent = allNodes.Where(x => x.Item2 == 5)
                          .Select(x => x.Item1)
                          .SingleOrDefault();
```

This has the benefit in the case where there is more than one element satisfying the provided predicate then you'll get an exception to indicate something is wrong.

Whereas the first approach would be hiding a bug, so decide wisely which approach to proceed with.

Comment: Thanks. works perfect. Sorry, wasn't known about this :(